# Curl Function Return Undefined Variable

Tags: php, curl

My problem is that the code i post is returning Undefined variable $responseXML

(curl.php)

```
<?php
function curl_seasson($url) {
    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $responseXML = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
}
?>
```

(index.php)

```
<?php
$url = "site.xml.format";

require_once("curl.php");

curl_seasson($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($responseXML);

\\
\\
?>
```

Comment: Your function is returning nothing

Comment: when i also try to return $responseXML after curl_close($c); again i get undefinded variable !.

Comment: return the variable: `$responseXML` in the function and assgin it in the index.php to `$responseXML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the xml data which you get from your curl call.

curl.php:

```
<?php
    function curl_seasson($url) {
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $responseXML = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);

        return $responseXML;
    }
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    $url = "site.xml.format";

    require_once("curl.php");

    $responseXML = curl_seasson($url);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($responseXML);

?>
```

Comment: Works, thnx a lot ! and sorry for any inconvenance !.